# Trying to use a list to populate cells in a row

Tags: python, csv

I want to use a list to populate a row of data cells.

```py
new_list = ['X', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'X', 'N', 'N', 'X', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'X', 'N', 'N',]

def new_list_report(new_list):
    with open('newlist.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
        thewriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
        for word in new_list:
            thewriter.writerow(word)
```

When I execute the code, it populates each data cell in a column. What I would like to do is instead populate each cell in a row. How could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want all the elements of `new_list` to appear as cells in a single row? Then write the whole list as a row, instead of each element of `new_list` as a row.

```
new_list = ['X', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'X', 'N', 'N', 'X', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'X', 'N', 'N',]

def new_list_report(new_list):
    with open('newlist.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
        thewriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
        thewriter.writerow(new_list)
```